# JavaScript how to handle Node callbacks correctly, code running out of order when importing functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to JS and Node, i've been trying to write an API for people management like keeping track of employees absences and I'm using Node with express.js.

I currently ran into a problem of ordering when i decided to put the functions in their own module/file.

I basically want to retrieve a employee absences when a manager does a GET request on **localhost:3000/user/$userId** , but my functions are running out of order and i've been reading about node callbacks but i still couldn't figure it out.

Code of the API call:

```
/* Returns for each employee find her/his absences */
app.get('/user/:userId', async (req, res) => {
  let employee = api.getEmployeeAbsences(req.params.userId);
  console.log(`Employee retrivied ${employee}`);
});
```

Code of the API function that retrives the employee and his absences.

```
const readJsonFile = (path) => new Promise((resolve) => fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', (_, data) => resolve(data)))
  .then((data) => JSON.parse(data))
  .then((data) => data.payload);

export const members = () => readJsonFile(MEMBERS_PATH);
export const absences = () => readJsonFile(ABSENCES_PATH);

var exports = module.exports = {};

/* Returns the employee(given by the userId) info and his last absence if she or he exists */
exports.getEmployeeAbsences = function(userId) {
  console.log('Start of Function');
  members().then((employees) => {
    console.log('Members');  
    let employee = employees.filter(emp => userId == emp.userId)[0];
    // If employee wasn't found
    if (!employee) {
      return undefined;
    } else {
      absences().then((absences) => {
        console.log('Absences');
        // Assigning employee absences
        employee = Object.assign(employee, { absences: absences.filter(abs => employee.userId == abs.userId) });
        console.log(employee);
        return employee;
      });
    }
  });
  console.log(`End of function ${userId}`);
}
```

Out of Order Output Example:

[image: Out of order output]

Comment: You need to `return` each `Promise` call. eg `return members().then(...` and `return absences()...` and call `.then` on the resulting `Promise` in the consumer (or use `await`)

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks for the quick reply, I'm still a beginner with node and JS so i didn't exactly know what to search for and i didn't find that answer.